# c++ clone function in abstract class

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, clone

in c++11 standard, if class B inherits from class A, then 'B is an A'. 
However, i am still confused regarding this notion: 
look at this code:

```
class Base {
public: 
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual Base* clone() const = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    virtual Base* clone() const {
        return new Derived(*this);
    }
    //<more functions>
};
```

we returned a pointer to Base from Derived, but if using this approach in this code:

```
Derived* d1 = new Derived();
Derived* d2 = d1->clone();
```

what we did is assigning `Base*` in `Derived*`!!

**The Problem**:
why this code does not compile? How could it be modified(and why?) in order to fit with the inheritance?

Comment: The code you have posted does not compile. Please post working code. Especially if your question is "How come this code compiles?".

Comment: Even if I write `Derived d1;` instead of `Derived d1 = new Derived();` it does not compile. In VS 2013 I get the expected error message "cannot convert from 'Base *' to 'Derived *'" in the line where `d2` is declared.

Comment: I guess you meant to return `Derived*` type in the derived class, and this is called *covariance*

Comment: thanks for noting. i modified the question hoping it would be more clear, since i expect it to compile according to the standards and conditions of inheritance, that i am asking about.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The code you posted will not compile even after some trivial edits (which I made). The signature of the `Derived::clone()` should be:

```
virtual Derived* clone() const override {  // <-- return type
  return new Derived(*this);
}
```

Even though the return type of `clone()` in `Base` and `Derived` class are different, it's a valid overriding of `virtual` function because, the [**co-variance**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type) is legal in C++.

There won't be any slicing when you deal with the pointers as stated in your question.
`Derived::clone()` should return `Derived*`.

Whether the `clone()` should be `virtual` or not depends on the design, but with `virtual` destructor it's a good idea.

---

Another approach is to use a `template` and avoid `virtual`:

```
class Base {
public: 
    virtual ~Base() {}
    template<class T>  // now need not add this trivial code in all derived classes
    T* clone() const { return new T(*this); }
};
```

Comment: that answers my question. The saddle point i had, was the co-variance thing, and the slicing issue.
**im still a newbie in c++, so please excuse my primitive questions, since it's hard to find a reliable source for this language.

Comment: @ThunderWiring, Also pay attention at the (key)word `override` (-std=c++11) in the signature. If the `virtual` method signature is not matching with any method in its base class then it generates an error.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful answer! 
I wonder, is there a way to implement clone() once, as it is essentially duplicated over all derived classes?

Comment: @YuriFeldman, see the updated answer with using templates. In such case, we don't have to implement the same method again and again by adding boilerplate code.

Comment: The non-virtual and template clone ideas make little sense. If you have a Derived object/pointer/reference and you know it's really a Derived, just use its copy ctor to copy it.

Comment: @n.m., yes I agree. I have assumed that for this question, probably OP doesn't want to make such explicit copies. Sometimes people coming from C#/Java background, overtly rely on such "clone()" kind of interfaces.

Comment: exactly what n.m. said. Suppose one would want a _virtual_ copy function/copy ctor for each derived class.